# Would it be okay to ask a question about an algorithm from a paper that's not freely available?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've implemented the "inefficient but simple algorithm" from Derek Oppen's paper "Prettyprinting" from ACM's TOPLAS Volume 2, No. 4. However, it didn't work. After spending hours we think we've identified that the algorithm itself is wrong. I would like more people to look at it to be sure.

However, this paper is not freely available. This probably means I cannot reproduce the algorithm here. Is it a bad question because of this? Or would that simply restrict the people who can answer it to those who can access the paper?

Comment: Is the algorithm in the *TOPLAS* paper the same as the algorithm in [this technical report](http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/cs/tr/79/770/CS-TR-79-770.pdf)?

Comment: The typesetting and capitalization of some words are different; those are the differences I could find immediately. It may be the same algorithm. I'll try to scrutinize it for differences.

Answer (score 4):

> However, it didn't work.

It sounds like the question would be off-topic anyway.  But even if that weren't the case, then it would likely not do so well here.  It's best to have as much information embedded in the post as possible, *especially* the code itself.

Answer (score 3):

Sure.  It has been done before.

- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/122103/9357
- [Melsort — Sorting with encroaching lists](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/124980/9357)

Fair warning, though: a question that requires reading an academic paper is not very likely to receive a review about anything more than style issues.  There's only so much work that community members will do for <s>fake Internet points</s> free.

That said, if your code isn't working as intended, then the question would be altogether off-topic for Code Review.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding – I am fairly certain the algorithm outlined in the paper doesn't work, rather than my implementation of it. That's the whole premise of the question.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what you meant by "it". If it's pseudocode, it's off-topic. If it's not your own code, it's off-topic.